# How to modify join_defaults values in many_to_many changeset?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a many to many relationship between `Users` and `Organizations`, using a custom `Members` schema as a join table.

Simplified schemas:

```
schema "members" do
  field :role, :string
  field :organization_id, :id
  field :user_id, :id
end

schema "organizations" do
  field :name, :string
  many_to_many :users, App.Users.User, join_through: App.Organizations.Members, join_defaults: [role: "read"]
end

schema "users" do
  many_to_many :organizations, App.Organizations.Organization, join_through: App.Organizations.Members, join_defaults: [role: "read"]
end
```

Question: how can I modify Members' `role` parameter when creating new changesets? I.e. when I'm creating a new User (and Organization), how can I pass a `role` here such that it's a value other than the default?

```
user = User.changeset(%User{}, %{"organizations": [%{"name": "test org"}]}) 
|> Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc(:organizations, with: &App.Organizations.Organization.changeset/2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ([the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3-has_many-has_one-through)):

> Note :through associations are read-only. For example, you cannot use
> Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc/3 to modify through associations.

I usually approach these kinds of things with `Ecto.Multi`:

```
    user_attrs = %{"name" => "Alice"}
    organization_attrs = %{"name" => "The Club"}
    member_attrs = %{"role" => "Manager"}

    Ecto.Multi.new()
    |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:user, User.changeset(%User{}, user_attrs))
    |> Ecto.Multi.insert(
      :organization,
      Organization.changeset(%Organization{}, organization_attrs)
    )
    |> Ecto.Multi.insert(
      :member,
      fn %{user: %{id: user_id}}, %{organization: %{id: organization_id}} ->
        Member.changeset(
          %Member{},
          Enum.into(member_attrs, %{"user_id" => user_id, "organization_id" => organization_id})
        )
      end
    )
    |> Repo.transaction()
    |> case do
      {:ok, %{user: user, organization: organization, member: member}} -> {:ok, user}
      {:error, _, changeset, _} -> {:error, changeset}
    end
```

I haven't tried to compile that code so it might need tweaking.